# DDNS on my .com domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

com domain with some subdomains
all dns A records point to the same IP of my computer (used as a server) that host a kubernetes cluster, subdomains are used for the routing.

Since I have a dynamic IP (instead of a static one) and I cannot have a static IP
is there a way to configure my domain to use DDNS? my domain is hosted on IONOS

Sorry, but I have no experience in this and I hope the question is clear.
Thanks

Comment: Why does your business not have a fixed address? That is usually for residential ISP connections.

Answer (score 2):

OVH is providing dynamic DNS service for subdomains only, but the main record needs to point to a static IP.

In short, you **can't** point example.com as DDNS, but you **can** add [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as DDNS.

Not sure about your provider, just sharing my experience with OVH. Hope it helps.

Comment: so you can do ddns with OVH? is there a client or something before I transfer the domain?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here you can find more information https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/domains/hosting_dynhost/

I had a script for this running in a docker container.